# ios custom tableViewCell height changes trailing unused rows and removes cell border

Tags: ios, height, uitableview, trailing

In the storyboard I have configured my prototype cell to have a height of 132.

[image]

So I implemented

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

to return 132 for this specific row. In the simulator, it shows up like this:

[image]

Row 0 is the row with the "Notes" title and row 1 is my special cell with height 132. There are no other rows implemented in this section.

The problem is the trailing rows after row 1 also take on the height of 132. Also, the border between row 1 and "row 2" (I say "row 2" in quotes because I haven't implemented a row 2 but it shows up as a trailing row) is gone for some reason but you can see the separation if I select row 1 as shown here:

[image]

So my questions are:

1. How can I make it so the trailing rows are the default size of 44?
2. Why is the border between row 1 and "row 2" gone and how can I get it back?

Answer (score 0):

1) Use this method to set height of rows

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      int heightRow;
      if(indexPath.row==1)
         heightRow = 132;
      else
          heightRow = 44;
    return heightRow;
}
```

2) For Border - Check `autoresizing` of `tablecells`. Have you implemented default separator or showing it with some `image`? If you are using an `image` Try checking it's `frame`.

Comment: I'm already using that method to set the height of the rows and I get the behavior I showed. Where is the autoresizing feature located? The separator is default.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my second question of the border disappearing. I was forgetting to call 
    [super layoutSubviews]